# PowerShell creating random ps1 scripts in Windows Temp

Tags: windows, powershell

I noticed recently that Sysmon logs an event Powershell creating a file in Windows Temp folder.

For example, this is the name of PS Script:

```
C:\\Windows\\Temp\\xgyxfpqs.ilw.ps1
```

I would like to know what is the cause of this and especially whether such files are product of some malicious activity going on. The name pattern is always the same, but the the actual characters differ.

Because I investigated similar issue with *PS Script Policy Test*. However, in that case, you would clearly see in the directory path '__PSScriptPolicyTest_' which is not present in the above scenario - although it still follow the pattern of *8 chars '.' 3 chars*.

Any insights would be useful.

Comment: Even though you have some mystery powershell files, the question is not about Powershell itself as you have no Code. I would say this question would be better suited to [su] as a general question about Windows and/or Malware.

Comment: I will try my luck there. Thanks